# Wrong color of video after using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm generating a video and add `backgroundView` on a background of it.

`BackgroundView` contains color or image.

While using `AVAssetExportSession` we can't add a background to the video. That's why I generate background video from `backgroundView`.

```
guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition,presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
export.videoComposition = mainComposition
export.outputFileType = .mp4
export.outputURL = exportURL
export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
```

After that add `AVURLAsset` via instructions on the background to the video. And generate the final one.

```
guard let track = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else { return nil }
do {
    try track.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, end: asset.duration),
                                      of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!, at: .zero)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
return AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
```

And the problem that I've got incorrect color. After generating from image it's correct, but after adding as instructions it became lighter.

**Update**

Found that after `AVAssetExportSession` change the color of the video. It doesn't depend on instructions, it also changed if add the video to `videoLayer`.

I have a video with solid color added[image]

and after export it changed to [image]

Video for test: [link for download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51847253429896053354)

## Update:

Added mainComposition and mixComposition

```
var mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
```

Using func for adding backgroundAsset like inout param.

```
    func addBackgroundAsset(_ asset: AVURLAsset?,
                            composition: inout AVMutableComposition) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction? {
        guard let asset = asset else { return nil}
        // Block with adding Background Image
        guard let track = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
            let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else { return nil }
        do {
            try track.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, end: asset.duration),
                                      of: assetTrack, at: .zero)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        instruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
        return instruction
    }

        let mainInstruction = mainInstruction
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, end: duration)
        mainInstruction.layerInstructions = instructions
        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)
        mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer,
                                                                            in: outputLayer)
```

Comment: Don't you think that it is just effect of compression?

Comment: Input video size 1080*1920, and output 1080*1920, they are same.

Comment: I did not mean size compression, but codec - google for "h264 gamma shift"

Comment: @Asperi Maybe you are right. How can I change it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse` to false?

Comment: @elliott-io yes, but it doesn't help

Comment: Are you doing any transformation to the video like scaling? If so, try to set the transform matrix back to `CGAffineTransform.identity`.

Comment: @Manuel no transform applied for this video.

Comment: What is the code for your `mixComposition` and `mainComposition` ?

Comment: This is a bug and I have already filed a radar. Just giving you a heads up. I burned an ATS ticket to chat with them about this.

Comment: @user2398911, would you provide the background color as mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a backgroundColor via instruction, only *solid* BGRA colors are supported.

What is your background color set to (and does it have an alpha value)?

> Apple Documentation on [`AVVideoCompositionInstruction.backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositioninstruction/1389384-backgroundcolor?preferredLanguage=occ):
>
> Only solid BGRA colors are supported; patterns and other supported
> colors are ignored. If the rendered pixel buffer does not have alpha,
> the alpha value of the background color is ignored.
>
> If the background color is NULL, the video compositor uses a default
> background color of opaque black.

Comment: @elliot-io - Sorry for the late response, release days. As I mentioned in the question
`BackgroundView contains color or image.`. So your answer isn't correct. Also I have gradient.

Comment: Hey @user2398911, no worries. Maybe I wasn't clear. What is the exact color code of your background view? Does it have any alpha settings? You didn't mention a gradient before, that is important, what is it set to in the example above? The documentation quoted in my answer says `AVVideoCompositionInstruction.backgroundColor` only supports solid BGRA colors (not gradients). Have you tried setting a solid BGRA color and exporting? Which one?